# Is it possible find the jacobian of inverse radial distortion (cv2.undistortPoints)?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am writing my camera calibration algorithm and encountered the following difficulty.

Given a pin hole camera model, the radial distortion is modeled by the following equation
[image]
[image]

where x, y is the ideal normalized image coordinate, x_head is the coordination of x after distorted.

The question is how to find the partial derivative of k1, k2, k3 for the inverse distortion function?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) applies to multivariate continuously differentiable functions too.

That said, unless you are doing some theorem-proving work, I am going to guess that you really do not need the inverse jacobian for calibrating a camera, and maybe you need to rethink your problem a little more.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to find the jacobian of the inverse function (dx/d k1,k2,k3) based on the jacobian of the inverse function (dx_head/d k1,k2,k3)

Comment: Read the linked wiki page. Strictly speaking, in your case the function is not invertible, because the domain is 3d and the codomain is 2d. You can do 3d continuation defining a third dependent variable, e.g. z = k1 + k2 + k3